# When sending an application to USCIS for OPT do I need to send the "F-1 Graduation Form"?

Tags: usa

My student adviser, whom I gave all of my documents to, gave me back a set of prepared documents to send to USCIS. Omitted from those documents was my F-1 Graduation Form, which I gave to that adviser. Do I need to send the F-1 Graduation Form? Or is it just used for the adviser to prepare the I-20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the US government [instructions for filing Form I-765](https://www.uscis.gov/i-765).  Since the same form is used for OPT and for various other applications, the instructions are long and only some parts are relevant for OPT.  Here are more [general instructions about OPT from Homeland Security](https://studyinthestates.dhs.gov/sevis-help-hub/student-records/fm-student-employment/f-1-optional-practical-training-opt).

"F-1 Graduation Form" isn't mentioned in the instructions, so I believe you shouldn't include it unless your adviser says otherwise.  It may be a form used internally by your university.